# What are the bosses references to in Violent Storm?

Tags: reference, character-similarity, violent-storm

The 1993 Konami video game "[Violent Storm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violent_Storm)" features a lot of allusions to earlier works in various media.  The whole game is patterned after Capcom's "[Final Fight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fight)"—itself a game with characters named after [Andre the Giant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_the_Giant) and [Axl Rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guns_N%27_Roses)—and other homages to Capcom include martial artists enemies named "[Ryuken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_Fighter)."  There are enemies with 1980s hair metal hairstyles named "[Gigadeath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megadeth)," and near the end of the game, the action passes through an arcade where the villains are playing "[[Tsurikko] Penta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsurikko_Penta)" and "[Scramble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scramble_(video_game))."

Where the game really departs from the style of "Final Fight," "[Renegade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renegade_(video_game))," "[Crime Fighters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crime_Fighters)," and "[Vendetta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vendetta_(1991_video_game))"—arcade brawlers combining gameplay like "[Double Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Dragon_(video_game))" with an outre urban esthetic drawing inspiration from *[The Warriors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Warriors_(film))*—was that the bosses were mostly overtly fantastical or science-fictional characters (in contrast to the regular enemies).  "Violent Storm" was not alone in this respect.  Irem's 1992 game "[Undercover Cops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undercover_Cops)" also had sci-fi and fantasy bosses mixed into its otherwise initially realistic-seeming urban hellscape; however, apart from the first boss in "Undercover Cops" being an obvious *[Terminator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terminator)* stand-in, the enemies seemed largely like unique esoteric creations.  In "Violent Storm," in contrast, several—maybe all—of the bosses appear to be specific homages to other fantasy and science fiction characters.  In fact, as I was watching part of a playthrough today, I seem to remember a claim (probably read on the Internet some time in the late 1990s) that every single one of the bosses was meant to invoke aspects of some other famous properties.

Here are the eight bosses in the game, with brief descriptions and video cues.  What are they each homaging?

**Dabel**
A hooded goon, with only one eye peeking out of his white executioner's hood, fighting with a spiked mace

**Joe**
A miniature, hunchbacked train conductor with a huge electrified ticket punch and bell for summoning more enemies

**Drigger**
A giant bare-chested barefoot barbarian, with a horned skull for a helmet

**Doyle**
A goggled, orange-mohawked man wearing a bright yellow apparatus combining a jetpack and mechanical claws

**Mr. Julius**
A stone statue that comes to life, appearing as a bodybuilder dressed in an aqua thong and with what looks like interdigital webbing on this sides of the metal fillet circling his head

**Sledge**
A man with a round head fully covered by a purple domino mask, tied around the back with its tails hanging loose; armed and armored with with wok-shaped plates

**Red Fredy**
A goblin-like figure with green skin and spiky orange hair, wearing a stereotypical Turkish vest, pantaloons, and bangles, and with long, sharp nails

**Geld**
Squeaky-voiced, purple-skinned character, who grows to superhuman size and strength, looking like his swollen flesh has been stitched together, and who shoots green fireballs and flames

Some of the allusions that partially underlie these characters are obvious, and I am creating a community wiki answer with what I (with the assistance of my teenaged daughter) have been able to guess at.

Answer (score 1):

**Dabel**
???
My daughter suggested that the bag over his head gives him a significant resemblance to [Oogie Boogie](https://youtu.be/clURHZ5TfCQ?t=42) from *The Nightmare Before Christmas*.  However, that came out in October 1993, apparently too late to influence "Violent Storm."  There may, though, be another character that both Dabel and Oogie Boogie are references to.

**Joe**
??
His ticket puncher looks a lot like a giant pair of scissors, but it's not clear what specific scissors-wielding villain Joe homages.  "[Clock Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_Tower_(1995_video_game))" is too late, and I think the scissors in *Phenomena* (1985), which inspired the scissors-wielding villain in "Clock Tower," were normal sized.

**Drigger**
??
Apart from commonplace "barbarian" elements, I haven't identified a specific reference.

**Doyle**
Doyle's apparatus, with its yellow grabbing claws, is taken from the iconic appearance of the power loader in *[Aliens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliens_(film))*.

[image: Ripley operating the power loader]

**Mr. Julius**
???

**Sledge**
Despite apparently being dressed in pieces of cookware, Sledge is obviously recognizable as a *[Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teenage_Mutant_Ninja_Turtles)* reference.  His mask resembles the turtle's headbands, and the "woks" on his muscular chest and arm look like the their shells.  His ability to disappear in a cloud of smoke further alludes to the "ninja" element.

[image: Donatello, the turtle with purple headgear]

**Red Fredy**
His name and nails are obviously allusions to [Freddy Krueger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freddy_Krueger) from *[A Nightmare on Elm Street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Nightmare_on_Elm_Street)*, a 1984 slasher film.

[image: Freddy Krueger]

**Geld**
?
His transformation, fireballs, and spiky hair may be allusions to Dragonball characters (perhaps particularly Vegeta) and their super saiyan transformations.

[image: Vegeta]